# Nmap showing port is filtered, but apache files are listening to port 80

Tags: ubuntu, apache-2.4, linux-networking

I am having trouble with apache on my Ubuntu server. It is not a local machine, I am accessing it through SSH.
When I run `nmap -sS 127.0.0.1` it shows this:

```
Not shown: 998 closed ports
PORT   STATE    SERVICE
22/tcp open     ssh
80/tcp filtered HTTP
```

ports.conf is setup listening to port 80 like so:

```
Listen 80

<IfModule ssl_module>
        Listen 443
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_gnutls.c>
        Listen 443
</IfModule>
```

Its worth mentioning I also tried setting it to `Listen 0.0.0.0:80`

I cant seem to get port 80 to open as opposed to being set to filtered.
When I run `sudo ufw status verbose` its saying:

```
Status: active
Logging: on (low)
Default: deny (incoming), allow (outgoing), disabled (routed)
New profiles: skip

To                         Action      From
--                         ------      ----
80,443/tcp                 ALLOW IN    Anywhere
22/tcp                     ALLOW IN    Anywhere
80,443/tcp (v6)            ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)
22/tcp (v6)                ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)
```

So I don't think its a firewall issue. What could be the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu has two firewalls:

- `ufw` - Which you checked
- `iptables` (aka netfilter) - Which is a lower level firewall that is used by `ufw`.

It's possible that `iptables` is still blocking access even through it's allowed in `ufw`.

To check, you'll need to have some knowledge of iptables. Check your tables with a command like this:

```
iptables --table filter --list --numeric
```

And look for anything that is either blocking port 80, or if there's a default rule to `DROP` all traffic that doesn't match a previous rule.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I ran that command, but I don't really understand what I'm looking at. I get that their rules, but not sure if any of them are affecting my server. I pasted it in a pastebin if you don't mind taking a look. [pastebin](https://pastebin.com/FF0QU7ww)

Comment: `sudo iptables -S` shows the true state of system network filtering. You can read the explanation of each line with `man iptables`. The `ufw` is just a frontend software that creates needlessly complicated rules for `iptables`.